# OKTA Session API

Tags: okta, okta-api

Is there an API (we are using the OKTA Sign In Widget) to get the original res.idToken?

Reason I ask is that users might hit our site after logging in to a different site and we need the idToken.  We can tell if the session exists of course..

```
  oktaSignIn.session.exists((exists) => {

  if (exists) { oktaSignIn.session.get((res) =>
```

But I don't see an idToken in there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use tokenManager to store the tokens?
After receiving the id token, you can add it a **tokenManager**. The token can later be retrieved from there.
Refer - https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget#oidc-tokenmanageraddkey-token

Comment: Thanks...  our issue if that we have a portal.. users go there and login .. we (our app) is but a link from this portal (which we have no control over).  We just want to ensure that a user is entitled to our app (they can login to the portal.. then go to our app... session api says we have a session.... but.. are they really entitled?)

So... we want to find out.  I've also tried using  {{url}}/api/v1/apps?filter=user.id+eq+"{{userId}}"&expand=user/{{userId}}   but it always returns an empty array.

That however, would give me what I need...

tx again for the response....

Answer (score 0):

Well.. seems like I can get a new IDToken.  The docs say this:

```
oktaSignIn.idToken.refresh(token, function (newToken) {
  // New id_token with extended lifetime
});
```

My problem of course was that I did not have have a token to refresh.  Turns out you can just do... (use null instead of a token)

```
oktaSignIn.idToken.refresh(null, function (newToken) {
  // New id_token with extended lifetime
});
```

Hopefully this is not a bug but a feature :-)